# Logged in as Admin on Wordpress makes MAMP run slowly

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

When using MAMP to develop a Wordpress theme locally and when logged in as Admin the website loading time slows down dramatically. It would appear something is still being downloaded, however when the theme is moved to production everything is fine. I have the same issue when I use another theme eg `twenty seventeen`

**Locally**
[image]

**Production sever**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fix was reinstalling Wordpress